# Python: Overloading operators in classes

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

I am trying to make a Poly class which part of it is designed to add, subtract and multiply polynomials to int(s) and float(s).

+-* <= + or - or *

I have managed to do Poly +-* Poly and Poly +-* int/float. However, when I try to do int/float +-* Poly I get a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Poly.
I get this error for +, -, and *.

Why is that that I can add, subtract and multiply a Poly with an int but not an int with a poly? How do I make it so that I can also do int + Poly?

I did not want to post my code, because it was complex and hard to understand so I will summarize the add method here in a few lines:

```
    def __add__(self, right):
         if type(right) is in (int,float):
              return _add_num(self, right)
         elif type(right) is Poly:
              return _add_poly(self, right)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to implement the \_\_radd\_\_ method.

Comment: Would the __radd__ method flip the 2 inputs (self and right)?